# Databinding in VB.NET Modify Database Connection

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Anybody here have an idea how to modify connection from database using databinding in VB.NET if I am going to copy the file project and then save it to another computers and run. I am using microsoft access database, the error occurs is microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine. How to fix this problem so that every time i need to copy my project to another computer the error will not occur again.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver is not installed on vanilla Windows systems. If you use an installation program you can craft ways to install it or alert the user to install it manually. Here's a link to the redistributable download: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255

Comment: I found this great tutorials @ this site: http://www.tesear.com/2012/10/how-to-fix-error-microsoftaceoledb120.html